# Extract data from a website to a .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, web-scraping

I'm trying every example I found in here since a week now (even tried to convert some example from JavaScript to VBA), but can't put the finger on something that worked for the website I want

Website: https://www.inspq.qc.ca/covid-19/donnees

Manually I can click on the 3 dots upper-right of every chart, click the "Télécharger les données en format CSV" option and I get the raw data of the chart in a .csv file

When I inspect the element I saw:

```
<g class="highcharts-button highcharts-contextbutton                 highcharts-button-normal" stroke-linecap="round" transform="translate(1412,10)"><rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-button-box" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="24" height="22" rx="2" ry="2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"></rect><title>Chart context menu</title><path fill="#666666" d="M 12.666666666666666 6.666666666666668 A 1.3333333333333335 1.3333333333333335 0 1 1 12.667999999777779 6.666666000000056 Z M 12.666666666666666 13.333333333333336 A 1.3333333333333335 1.3333333333333335 0 1 1 12.667999999777779 13.333332666666724 Z M 12.666666666666666 20 A 1.3333333333333335 1.3333333333333335 0 1 1 12.667999999777779 19.999999333333392 Z" class="highcharts-button-symbol" data-z-index="1" stroke="#666666" stroke-width="3"></path><text x="0" data-z-index="1" style="color:#333333;cursor:pointer;font-weight:normal;fill:#333333;" y="12"></text></g>
```

But I don't understand how to change every example I found here to click on this button and choose the option that export raw data to a CSV file

Comment: I'm quite sure that is done using javascript and/or jquery. If you look in the source you see that the page has a lot of javascript and at least two jquery codes. The code to generate the csv can be hidden anywhere in there

Comment: I tried to monitor the network as I pressed the link but nothing appeared in the log. I assume it's javascript then.

Answer (score 0):

We have nothing to do with JS because the IE does that automaticaly for us. We "only" have to automate the IE.

To manage the downloads we must use `Sendkeys()`. This is not very elegant, but I do not know any other solution for donloads like theese. For that reason the IE must be shown and it **must** have the focus!

The files will be saved in your standard download directory of the IE. They have all the same name *chart.csv*. But that's no problem, because Windows will add an own number to every file name. So the file without number is the first one. All others are numbered in the following order.

I have commented the code. So you can see how it works:

```
Sub DownloadCovidCSVs()

Const url As String = "https://www.inspq.qc.ca/covid-19/donnees"

Dim ie As Object
Dim nodesAllThreeDots As Object
Dim nodeOneThreeDots As Object
Dim nodeMenueEntries As Object
Dim timeout As Double
Dim failed As Boolean

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate url
  Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  
  'Start time for timeout if the charts would'nt load
  timeout = Timer
  'Waiting until the charts were loaded or timeout takes effect
  Do
    Set nodesAllThreeDots = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-contextbutton")
  Loop Until nodesAllThreeDots.Length > 0 Or Timer - timeout > 30 'Timeout in seconds
  
  'Check if charts not been loaded
  If nodesAllThreeDots.Length = 0 Then
    failed = True
  End If
  
  'If charts were loaded, download csv files
  If Not failed Then
    For Each nodeOneThreeDots In nodesAllThreeDots
      'Open current menu
      nodeOneThreeDots.Click
      
      'Get the last entry and click it to initialize download
      Set nodeMenueEntries = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-menu-item")
      nodeMenueEntries(nodeMenueEntries.Length - 1).Click
      
      'Give the server time to generate the document and the IE to show the download button at it's bottom
      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
      
      'Attention!
      'We have to use SendKeys to perform the download!!!
      'As long as the macro is running, keep your fingers away from the mouse and keyboard!!!
      Application.SendKeys ("%{S}")
    Next nodeOneThreeDots
  End If
  
  'Clean up
  ie.Quit
  Set nodesAllThreeDots = Nothing
  Set nodeOneThreeDots = Nothing
  Set nodeMenueEntries = Nothing
End Sub
```